# Specifying percentiles in an aggregation dictionary with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am summarising a variable 'CSC130' using an aggregation dictionary and have a question around how to get a 25th percentile, 75th percentile values.

The quantile summary function is mentioned in the documentation but I can't see the syntax for how to use it?

How would I add a line to get the 25th percentile value for 'CSC130' using this dictionary

many thanks!

```
aggregations = {
    'CSC130': { 
        'CSC130_sum': 'sum',  
        'CSC130_mean': 'mean',
        'CSC130_min': 'min',
        'CSC130_max': 'max',
        'CSC130_count': 'count',
        'CSC130_size': 'size',
        'CSC130_range': lambda x: max(x) - min(x), 
        'CSC130_npmean': lambda x: np.mean(x),
        'CSC130_median': 'median'

        }
}

sumry = df.groupby(['POSTCODE']).agg(aggregations)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is simply

```
yourseries.quantile(yourquantile)
```

So just add these lines -

```
'CSC130_25quant': lambda x : x.quantile(0.25)
'CSC130_75quant': lambda x : x.quantile(0.75)
```

Comment: Just noticed though that the difference with the lambda functions included in terms of processing time is massive. 1.22 minutes for 4M records. vs less than a second with no lambda functions. Is there any faster way. Could we make the describe() function work to give percentiile data without any lambdas? thx again.